# How to use an OR statement within a LINQ Where statment

Tags: c#, linq

Basically, I want to see if a given string is contained in one of the four database entries.
Example of what I want done:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTagName))
{

   Articles = Articles.Where(b => b.Tag1.Contains(searchTagName));
   OR
   Articles = Articles.Where(b => b.Tag2.Contains(searchTagName));
   OR
   Articles = Articles.Where(b => b.Tag3.Contains(searchTagName));
   OR
   Articles = Articles.Where(b => b.Tag4.Contains(searchTagName));
}
```

How can I write in a proper

statement?

Comment: Please, do not include a languge tag in a title unless it wouldn't made sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should create one lambda expression out of it:

```
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTagName))
    {
       Articles = Articles.Where(b => 
                b.Tag1.Contains(searchTagName) ||
                b.Tag2.Contains(searchTagName) || 
                b.Tag3.Contains(searchTagName) ||
                b.Tag4.Contains(searchTagName));
    }
```

Comment: That is so strange, i tried that but i guess my visual studio was acting up. Sorry for the stupid question

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTagName))
{
   Articles = Articles.Where(b => 
                    b.Tag1.Contains(searchTagName) 
                 || b.Tag2.Contains(searchTagName) 
                 || b.Tag3.Contains(searchTagName) 
                 || b.Tag4.Contains(searchTagName));
}
```